# Special HTML characters in meta tag description

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

My `metatag description` contains a text with accents or special caracteres. 
I'm creating it in `Controller` MVC and I send to `view` through of `viewbag`.

By the way, my text `html` (when I use browser's *view HTML sourcecode*) is getting  with a different code.
Example:
**orign text**: Produtor's Event em 10 Kirkpatrick St, até N...
**html text**: Produtor's Event em 10 Kirkpatrick St, at&#233...

I need to care about this? Or I need to correct to a new code? How can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easier.

Use `@Html.Raw`

`<meta name="description" content="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.description)" />`